# How can I get the HP RC6 ir (HP SPS : 435743-001) Remote for my Laptop to also work on my desktop

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, xbmc, lirc

I Have this remote[image: remote] and it works with XBMC in Windows 7 64bit.

I would like to know if it is possible to also get this to work with my Ubuntu 11.10 64bit system.

I am not sure what I need to get it to work correctly because all the hardware is there for it on my laptop. I have a usb bluetooth dongle I would like to use if possible but if I need to but a Ir receiver or something like that I can try that too.

The reason why I am wanting to do it this way is so I can take advantage of using the remote on both systems.

If I can't get it to work with my bluetooth dongle then can you suggest somewhere local I can pick up the receiver? I have the following local stores : Radio Shack, Best Buy, Target, Walmart. I also use online stores like New Egg, Amazon, Ebay as my last option.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RC6 remotes all use Infrared (`ir`), not Bluetooth.

The only reliable source (i.e. won't disappear or be out of stock all of a sudden) to buy those receivers that I know of is Ebay. Ironically, it's almost cheaper to buy a remote + receiver bundle than to buy the receiver alone.

The receiver alone (with a Lenovo branding) currently costs $14-$20, a fullsize remote + receiver bundle (with various vendor brandings) $19-$25. Kinda weird, but oh well..

Search for *RC6 receiver* or *RC6 remote*, then select only the *computers & networking* category. RC6 is a Philips Infrared communication standard, so they should all be compatible with each other for the most part.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up buying a remote and receiver that is working great. Thanks again for the great info you provided because it helped a lot and helped me pinpoint what and how I needed to search for what I needed.

Comment: @Patrik Where can i get the battery for this remote?

Answer (score 0):

No not possible, it is only possible on HP Pavillion DV Series like HP Pavillion DV6345 or HP Pavillion DV2742 Laptops doesn't matter weather 2000s or 6000s it doesn't matter what first number is in the thousands place, it matters that it is an HP Pavillion DV like HP Pavillion DV6345 or HP Pavilion DV2742, they are just the specific kind of Model of DV Series Models of HP Pavillions